# N-point FFT and 2-radix FFT

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am wondering what is the difference between a N-point FFT (output has same length as the input) and a 2-radix FFT (output is always of length $2^n$)

For example
a is a sequence:

```
1     2     3     5     2     1     1
```

N-point FFT of a:

```
 15.0000 + 0.0000i    
 -4.3264 - 4.0333i    
  1.0930 + 2.2383i    
 -0.7666 - 1.7950i     
 -0.7666 + 1.7950i      
  1.0930 - 2.2383i    
 -4.3264 + 4.0333i
```

2-radix FFT (8-point in this case)

```
 15.0000 + 0.0000i    
 -3.8284 - 6.2426i    
 -1.0000 + 2.0000i      
  1.8284 - 2.2426i     
 -1.0000 + 0.0000i      
  1.8284 + 2.2426i    
 -1.0000 - 2.0000i    
 -3.8284 + 6.2426i
```

Also, is the relation between N-point FFT and 2-radix FFT, and how it they are? Can 2-radix FFT be converted to N-point FFT if possible?

Thanks  a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relation, the 8 point FFT is of the modified sequence that has a zero added. So it is a result for a different input.

See [Bluestein's chirp-z algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluestein%27s_FFT_algorithm) or [Raders algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rader%27s_FFT_algorithm) for a transformation of general N-point DFT into a form that a dyadic FFT may be applied.